# Dump and Restore Redis on PHP (predis)

Tags: php, redis, predis, phpredis

How can I dump and restore the redis database on PHP, I'm using [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) on my client.

Can I dump the redis database on .rdb format ?

**Updated :**

I dump/backup database using the following command,

```
$redis->bgSave();
```

How to restore it back to my database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Malinga, Restoring happen in the restart of redis server. So you need set appendonly no. So that it will use the .rdb file.

So, I created a sample program to backup and restore redis database, Here is the [code](https://github.com/sivasankars/redis-backup-restore-php) you can [check](https://github.com/sivasankars/redis-backup-restore-php)

**Export :**

```
$i = 0;
$json = array();
foreach($redis->keys('*') as $key) {
    $data = array();
    $data['key'] = $key;
    $data['ttl'] = $redis->ttl($key);
    $data['value'] = bin2hex($redis->dump($key));
    $json[$i] = $data;
    $i++;
}
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=database.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

**Import :**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Import') {
    $types = array(
        'application/json',
        'application/octet-stream'
    );
    if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $types)) {
        var_dump($_FILES);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['upload']['name']))
            {
            $file = file_get_contents('uploads/' . $_FILES['upload']['name'], "r");
            $database = json_decode($file, true);
            foreach($database as $data)
                {
                if ($data['ttl'] >= 0)
                    {
                    $data['ttl'] = $data['ttl'];
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $data['ttl'] = 0;
                    }

                if ($data['key'] && $data['value'] && !$redis->exists($data['key']))
                    {
                    $redis->restore($data['key'], $data['ttl'], hex2bin($data['value']));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Full code can be downloaded via [GitHub](https://github.com/sivasankars/redis-backup-restore-php)

Answer (score 1):

In redis you can use SAVE or BGSAVE to create a snapshot. However use of BGSAVE is recommended as SAVE will block all the other clients.

To do that in predis, it should be possible through

```
$client->executeRaw(['BGSAVE']);
```

Sorry I haven try this with predis. So first check if the client allow something like

```
$client->bgsave();
```

if not try above

**Restoring** happen in the restart of redis server. So you need set appendonly no. So that it will use the .rdb file

Comment: Yes, I got backup, How do i restore it back ?

Comment: Edited answer @ŞivāSankĂr

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am trying to build the code for dump and restore. Hope I got an idea now.

Comment: Ya I understand, as you can see there is no way to restore a dump other than redis server restart.